# Highcharts columnrange date chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

My goal is to make a chart that tracks user activity.  I want it to plot when they first logged on, and when they last logged on.

The data I pass into this function (`var refarray = [...data here...]`) is in string format, meaning I need to parse the dates given to me from the database into a date format, or so I thought. Below you will see my attempt.

```
function hc_first_last_logon(selector, refarray){
var categories = [];
var Dat = [];

for(var i = 0; i<refarray.length; i++){    // store all user names and data
    categories.push(refarray.name)
    Dat.push([Date.parse(refarray.FirstLogon), Date.parse(refarray.LastLogon)])
}
//console.log(Dat) returns date time objects as expected
var def = {
    chart: { type: 'columnrange', inverted: true },
    legend: { enabled: false},
    title:{ text: "First and Last Log-on"},
    xAxis:{ categories: categories, title:{text: "User"}},
    yAxis:{ type: 'datetime' },
    series:[{name: "First and Last Log-on", data: Dat}]
};
var div = $('#' + selector);
console.log(div);
div.highcharts(def);
return def;}
```

My intent is for this chart to be versatile, allowing me to choose any number of different users, and get the chart when I click a refresh button on my html page (it queries the database and sends the data to this function).

I suspect that my issue has to do with the date variable, `Dat`, as it appears that the string and date variable types are not acceptable data inputs for highcharts.

Here's an included screen shot of the errors that I am getting in the returned code.  The 10x2 matrix is pretty much all the same, so I'll only include one row.  Error #17 corresponds to unacceptable data type, which confirms my suspicions.

[Console Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZTND.png)

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:  I included highcharts-more.js, and now got rid of the error mentioned above.  The date ranges are still a bit off.  Below is an image of what's going on now.

[Current Chart Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xYqw.png)

Comment: Could you please show an example of output you get? How your Dat object looks?

Comment: Thank you, I included a screen shot of the console results in my question.

Comment: Error 17 is connected with wrong type of your series - not recognized by Highcharts. It is because you need to add highcharts-more.js module if you want to use columnrange type of your series. Here you can read information about this error: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17

Comment: okay, so I've added highcharts-more.js to the code, but it appears that it is still being picky with what i've fed into the chart, but it is a step forward.  I'll attach a picture of the result and console result above.  As a side question, in order to get some of the more specific charts, do I need to have highcharts-more.js or are all charts included in highcharts.js?  I was under the impression that most of their charting capabilities (columnrange included) was already accounted for in highcharts.js

Comment: If you have datetime time of your axis, Highcharts expects your dates in format of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970. You can simple convert this strings using for example Date.getTime(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: If I understand you correctly, with datetime axis Highcharts will label it for you. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jq3g9tg1/

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  @Grzegorz Blachliński and his suggestions, I was able to find the issue and resolve it. Here's what went wrong:

1) I did not load highcharts-more.js  Including this file resolved the Highcharts error 17.

2) Date needs to be in milliseconds from 1/1/1970.  Easy fix putting the dates generated into (datevar).getTime().

3) I did not have a tooltip formatter.  I copied one off the internet that got the job done, and it worked!

Here's the code for those interested:

```
function hc_first_last_logon(selector, refarray){
var categories = [];
var Dat = [];

for(var i = 0; i<refarray.length; i++){    // store all user names and data
    categories.push(refarray.name)
    Dat.push([Date.parse(refarray.FirstLogon).getTime(), Date.parse(refarray.LastLogon)].getTime())
}
//console.log(Dat) returns date time objects as expected
var def = {
    chart: { type: 'columnrange', inverted: true },
    legend: { enabled: false},
    title:{ text: "First and Last Log-on"},
    xAxis:{ categories: categories, title:{text: "User"}},
    yAxis:{ type: 'datetime' },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return new Date(this.point.low).toUTCString().substring(0, 22) + ' - ' + new Date(this.point.high).toUTCString().substring(0, 22)
        }
    },
    series:[{name: "First and Last Log-on", data: Dat}]
};
var div = $('#' + selector);
console.log(div);
div.highcharts(def);
return def;}
```